# Keras concatenation of certain values from LSTM layers

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm not sure if this is possible or not in Keras, but I would like to know is there any way to concatenate specific values from LSTM layers. 
I would like to encode whole sequence using LSTM but for prediction use only specific columns. 
For example:

- I'm using two input sequences with size of 5 (so my input shape is for one input is (None, 5) and (None, 5).
- Then I embed sequences and my input shape is (None, 5, 300) and (None, 5, 300)
- Then I encode sequence with LSTM layers with 200 LSTM cells and my final shape is (None, 5, 200) and (None, 5, 200).

Now I would like not to concatenate the whole sequence but the last 4 words encoded in lstm_1 and the first word in lstm_2.

```
> input_1 = Input(shape=(5, ))
> emb_1 = Embedding(..., 300, ...)(input_1)
> lstm_1 = CuDNNLSTM(200, ...)(emb_1)
> 
> input_2 = Input(shape=(5, ))
> emb_2 = Embedding(..., 300, ...)(input_2)
> lstm_2 = CuDNNLSTM(200, ...)(emb_2)
> 
> # here is the problem
> emb = concatenate([lstm_1[??], lstm_2[??])
> 
> d1 = Dense(...)(emb)
> out = Dense(..., activation="softmax")(d1)
```

Not sure if I'm making any sense but I would like to know if it's possible using Keras functional API.

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't realize that lstm_1 and lstm_2 are actually Numpy arrays that I can concatenate. So the solution is simple, you just need to wrap it in Lambda layer.

```
lstm_1_lambda = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -4:, :])(lstm_1)
lstm_2_lambda = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :1, :])(lstm_2)
emb = concatenate([lstm_1_lambda, lstm_1_lambda)
```

Best regards,
Daniel